# website/webserver outbound ip address

Tags: iis, ip-address

I am hoping there is a simple answer to this! My webserver has a number of IP addresses. one particular website has one of these IP addresses mapped to it. On said website, I have a java applet which is making outbound http requests.

Now, I am wondering what is the IP address that people will see for my server? Will they see the machine's default IP address or the IP address mapped in IIS for this website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java applet? So it's client side? It feels like a red herring.

The IP people will "see" (if they go looking) is whatever you set in the DNS, surely...

Perhaps you should specify which "people" you expect to see seeing your IP. If you mean the people owning the server you are making HTTPS requests to, *and* this is client side, they will see the IP of the website user. They won't see any of your IPs.

If this is server-side logic (ie something like a Java servlet), they will see whichever IP is the default outbound IP on that server. In some situations on *some* servers, the server will use the mapped IP, but as soon as you layer things out through connectors, it's anybody's guess which network adapter/IP actually gets used.

Answer (score 0):

The java applet will be run by your visitors. So the IP address to be seen will be the visitor one and not one that your server owns.